# Verilog expand each bit n times

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to expand each bit n times.
For example,

```
// n = 2
5'b10101 -> 10'b1100110011
// n = 3
5'b10101 -> 15'b111000111000111
```

Is there any simple way (i.e., not using generate block) in Verilog or SystemVerilog?

EDIT 19.02.21

Actually, I'm doing 64bit mask to 512bit mask conversion, but it is different from {8{something}}. My current code is the following:

```
logic [63 : 0] x;
logic [511 : 0] y;
genvar i;
for (i = 0; i < 64; i = i + 1) begin
    always_comb begin
        y[(i + 1) * 8 - 1 : i * 8] = x[i] ? 8'hFF : 8'h00;
    end
end
```

I just wonder there exists more "beautiful" way.

Comment: No, there is no way in verilog to do it in a simple way. Though you might use a repeat operator to do repeat groups, e.g. `{2'b11, {2{4'b0011}}}`

Comment: @Serge Thank you for reply. Actually, I need this functionality to convert bitmask into bytemask. e.g., `3'b010 -> 24'h00FF00` I ask, as you seem expert on verilog, is there any 'recommended' way to do it? Currently, I'm using generate block to iterate on each bit.

Comment: you need to provide a code sample. It might be a solution specific to your code. Most likely a `function` will do.

Comment: If you go from bit to byte, I would think your 'n' is always 8. Then you can use `{8{your_bit}}`

Comment: When dealing with bit widths in Verilog, there are different approaches if you know N is a constant as well the operands in the expression.

Comment: @Serge I provided a code sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your method is a good one. You cannot do it without some kind of a loop (unless you want to type all the iterations manually). There might be several variants for implementing it.

For example, using '+:' operator instead of an expression, which simplifies it a bit.

```
genvar i;
for (i = 0; i < 64; i = i + 1) begin
 always_comb begin
  y[i * 8 +: 8] = x[i] ? 8'hFF : 8'h00;
 end
end
```

Thew above method actually generated `64` always blocks (as in your original one). Though sensitivity list of every block will be just a single bit from 'x'.

You can move the `for` loop inside an always block:

```
always @* begin
 for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) begin
  y3[j * 8 +: 8] = x[j] ? 8'hFF : 8'h00;
 end
end
```

this will end up as a single always block, but sensitivity list will include all bits of  'x'.

If this operation is used multiple times, you can use a function :

```
function logic [511 : 0] transform(input logic [63 : 0] x);
 for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) begin
  transform[j * 8 +: 8] = x[j] ? 8'hFF : 8'h00;
 end
endfunction
...
always @* begin
 y = transform(x);
end
```

Comment: The ternary operator could also be written as a replication `y[i * 8 +: 8] = {8{x[i]}};`

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is a parameter you can do:

```
always_comb begin
  y = '0;
  for(int idx=0; idx<($bits(y)/n) && idx<$bits(x); idx++) begin
    y[idx*n +: n] = {n{x[idx]}};
  end
end
```

If `n` is a signal you have to assign each bit:

```
always_comb begin
  y = '0;
  foreach(y[idx]) begin
    y[idx] = x[ idx/n ];
  end
end
```

A variable divisor will add timing and area overhead. Depending on your design target, it may or may not be an issue (synthesis optimization or simulation only).